# propagate define to another sourcefile or set compiler flag in targetlink

Tags: c, linker, simulink, visual-c++-2010

I have the following problem:

As part of our (proprietary) test environment, we use `C` to map the developed C-Code to simulink/targetlink so we can compile it as a S-Function. The whole thing is compiled with visual-c(++)2010

In the development code there is a function that is only accessible when a certain flag/define is set by using `#ifdef` (because it is a function that gives the tester internal access to some data, which should not be accessible in production code).

- I tried raising the flag by -DFLAGNAME in the targetlink options. This doesn't help.
- I used `#define FLAGNAME` in my mapping code, this helped so far that the warning about the unknown function disappeared (so the header file accepted the flag), but I still get an error at link-time that he can not resolve the external symbol

I can't figure out how to access the function without modifying the development code. Below I try to give an example:

dev.h

```
#ifdef FLAGNAME
int* access(void);
#endif
```

dev.c

```
#include "dev.h"
#ifdef FLAGNAME
int* access(void){
return &data; //data has filescope
}
#endif
```

customCode.c (mapping code of targetlink)

```
#define FLAGNAME
#include "dev.h"
int main()
{
  int* bar = access();
  // do other things
}
```

I have access to all other functions in dev.c and the specific error is:

`customCode.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol access referenced in function main`

edit: I found the batch where the compile options are saved and modified it accordingly, this more or less was a solution for the problem.
But the question is still, would it be possible to propagate a define to another sourcefile, because this would make the solution portable.

Comment: Are you compiling `dev.c` with `-DFLAGNAME`? The linkage error strongly suggests you don't. In general, such flags for conditional compilation should be globally set.

Comment: @StoryTeller As I don't have direct access to the compiler (only through targetlink), the only possibility to give the compile option is via the option window in target link. There the option is given as stated. The problem might be that build S-Function (which is in another window) might not use these options but I don't know how to make it use any options at all there.

Comment: @StoryTeller I just remembered that there is a batch script somewhere in target link. I will look into it and maybe I can find something there.

Comment: @mch I could modify dev.c locally but the tests are shared over a version management tool and I can not modify it there so my solution would only work on my local PC which is not useful.

Comment: @StoryTeller The batch helped but the question still stands, is it possible to propagte the define?

Comment: I think it's time you asked a senior dev at your firm. There must be a way to set compiler flags globally, without too much hassle. If there isn't, that ad-hoc build system is rigid af.

Comment: @StoryTeller If I had one.... I work for a company that helps out the daughter (which wrote the codie) of the company that developed this tool (which is out of development). I may try asking dSpace (developer of targetlink) how this should be handled. Still if I understand this comment correctly I can not propagte the define to another .c file?

Comment: *"I can not propagte the define to another .c file?"* - pretty much. Macros are local to a translation unit, there's no way to know in `dev.c` whether or not something was defined in `customCode.c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the folder:

C:\Users*USERNAME*\AppData\Roaming\MathWorks\MATLAB*MATLABVERSION*

is the file mexopts.bat

there is a line which starts with `set COMPFLAGS=` (line 35 in my case)  after which all compilerflags may be defined.

There the needed flags can be raised.

In regard to StoryTellers comment in the question, it is not possible to propagate a define from one compilation unit to another.